# Do Transposes Have Equal Kernels When Their Quadratic Forms Are "Bounded"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix over a field $\Bbb F$. Must $\ker(\mathbf A)=\ker(\mathbf A^\perp)$ when the range of $\mathbf x\mapsto\mathbf{x^\perp Ax}$ is a $proper$ subset of $\Bbb F$ ?

Originally, this question was posted for $\Bbb F=\Bbb R$ and answered there in the affirmative using the canonical symmetric part of $\mathbf A$ and the positive semi-definite property given in that OP.

I wonder about the general case.

Comment: $\perp$ means transpose?

Comment: @kimchilover. Yes.

Comment: typical to prohibit characteristic 2

Comment: @WillJagy. I purposely included this case. I'm interested in the general case.

Comment: In that case, recommend L. Grove, Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra  https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-39/

Comment: @WillJagy. The book seems like a friendly and approachable introduction with concise emphasis in its final sections on special cases I find appealing. I will continue looking through. Thank you.